# Tkinter - Give name of variable option of a Scale through a class

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, parameters

I am starting to learn OOP and I've been struggling with some basic stuff.

In the code below, I have created a class `Scales()` that I want to use to create 2 very similar scales, with only their `variable` option being different.

How can I pass the name of these variables as a parameter when I call `Scales()` and make both of them a `DoubleVar` type?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np

class Scales(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, variable_name, label_text, initial_value,
                 final_value):

        self.parent        = parent
        self.bar_length    = 200
        self.variable_name = variable_name
        self.label_text    = label_text
        self.initial_value = initial_value
        self.final_value   = final_value

        # self.variable_name = DoubleVar()

        self.scale_name = Scale(self.parent, variable=self.variable_name,
                                orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                from_=self.initial_value,
                                to=self.final_value,
                                length=self.bar_length, cursor="hand",
                                label=self.label_text)


class MainApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.slice_number_scale = Scales(self.parent, slice_number,
                                         "Slice Number", 1, 24)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where are you trying to create a second instance of `Scale`? I only see one. Why do you need to give them names?

Comment: I've only created one so far. I need to use the values of both scales to perform an action in another widget. Therefore, I would need to use ``variable_name.get()`` later. To be more specific, each pair of values from the scale correspond to an image that will be show in a Canvas widget.

Comment: It's not clear why you have to give them unique names. Why can't they be `scale1` and `scale2`? `scales = Scales(...); ...; scales.scale1.get()... scales.scale2.get()`.

Comment: Don't we need to use .get() to the name of the 'variable' option in Scale?

So if I have: scale1 = Scale(parent, variable=variable_name, ...), shouldn't I use variable_name.get() to obtain the value of the scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the variables in each `Scale` class instance that is created, then access them through the instance's name. Here's what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#import numpy as np

class Scale(Frame):
    """ Dummy version of class for testing and illustration. """
    def __init__(self, parent, orient=None, from_=None, to=None, length=None,
                 cursor=None, label=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # initialize base class
        self.variable = DoubleVar()  # create variable and make attribute


class Scales(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label_text, initial_value,
                 final_value):

        self.parent        = parent
        self.bar_length    = 200
#        self.variable_name = variable_name
        self.label_text    = label_text
        self.initial_value = initial_value
        self.final_value   = final_value

#        self.variable_name = DoubleVar()

        self.scale1 = Scale(self.parent,
#                            variable=self.variable_name,
                            orient=HORIZONTAL,
                            from_=self.initial_value,
                            to=self.final_value,
                            length=self.bar_length,
                            cursor="hand",
                            label=self.label_text)

        self.scale1.pack()


class MainApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        slice_number = 42
        self.slice_number_scale = Scales(self.parent, slice_number, 1, 24)

root = Tk()
app = MainApplication(root)
app.mainloop()
```

After doing this you can access the variable for each `Scale` instance within a `Scales` instance as `self.scale1.variable` (and `self.scale2.variable` after you add it). Within the `MainApplication` instance they can be referred to as `self.slice_number_scale.scale1.variable` (and `self.slice_number_scale2.variable`).

For the latter you might want to add methods to class `MainApplication` to make such references more succinct, such as:

```
class MainApplication(Frame):
       ....
    def get_scale_var1(self):
        return self.slice_number_scale.scale1.variable.get()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped me to clarify some doubts I had about the usage of classes!

Comment: Done it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the variables are going to live as instance variables of your `Scales` class, then there's absolutely no reason to give them separate names; every reference to them is going to be in the context of some particular instance.  You'd probably want to define a `get()` method that does something like `return self.variable.get()`, for the convenience of the class's user.

If the variables live somewhere outside the class, then `Scales` should not care what their names are; pass the *variable itself* as a parameter to the class constructor, and pass it on as the `variable=` option to `Scale()`.